# stack overflow by using to big structure? (C) ARM M3

Tags: struct, arm

is it possible that a structure in a main.c  is so big, that its values cant be stored correctly?

How can I check what the reason is?

`myStructure.x= 122; myStructure.a= 2;`

reading out

`printf("%d", myStructure.a); "a"`

I declared it globally and then its values were stored correctly.

What is the difference declaring it globally?

It was on a microcontroller ARM M3.

Thank you.

I tried to debug it step by step. But there was no clue  why it behaves like that. Just writing wrong values..

So I just the same structure but this time globally. And it worked.

I checked the code and I saw that this global variable is once  declared extern

Minimal example:

**file1.c**

```
extern originalStruct myGlobalStruct;
```

**file2.c**

```
originalStruct{
    int a;
    int z;
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main(){
 

originalStruct myLocalStr; 



//reading sensor data:
myLocalStr.a=readInSensor();
myLocalStr.z= readInSensor();
//
myGlobalStruct.a=readInSensor();
myGlobalStruct.z= readInSensor();


//show  Struct Values:
// (also with gdb debugger)

printStruct(myLocalStr);// doesnt delivier the right values
printStruct(myGlobalStr); // does deliver the right values

return 1;}
```

Comment: you have not provided enough info, should work but there is something you are not showing us.  create a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not declared the stack correctly. You have to define the stack in the linker script.